# How to call a function in select statement which is having OUT parameter in it?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

If i have a function with OUT parameters then how can we call that function in  select statement.
my function is as below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_1 (p_in IN VARCHAR2, p_out OUT NUMBER)
RETURN number
AS
BEGIN
SELECT SAL INTO p_out FROM emp WHERE ename=P_in;
RETURN p_out;
END;
```

i want to call that function through select statement as below.

```
select fun_1('KING', lv_var) from dual;
```

is it possible. ?

Comment: on a different note, u can call in `blocks` right? why do you need in select?

Comment: yes we can call in blocks, i knew .. it is just my doubt that whether it's possible or not that's it.

Comment: Could you check my answer?

Comment: Which version of the database?

Comment: oracle 11g version

Comment: A function with an OUT parameter is a code smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this possible? 
**NO**

Because, with normal variable,it will give complile time error saying -

`"LV_VAR": invalid identifier`

Then I tried that using bind variables`(:lv_var)`. It gave run time error(after setting the bind variable). The reason is -

> **PL/SQL functions referenced by SQL statements must not contain the OUT parameter.**

```
ORA-06572: Function FUN_1 has out arguments
06572. 00000 -  "Function %s has out arguments"
*Cause:    A SQL statement references either a packaged, or a stand-alone,
           PL/SQL function that contains an OUT parameter in its argument
           list. PL/SQL functions referenced by SQL statements must not
           contain the OUT parameter.
*Action:   Recreate the PL/SQL function without the OUT parameter in the
           argument list.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is why most PL/SQL forbid functions from having out parameters.